# Unable to create new domain object in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi there i am still very new to grails and I have not been able to figure out why this is happening.

I have a domain class:

```
package scheduler

class Client {
  String name

  static constraints = {}
}
```

And a controller:

```
package scheduler
class AdminController {
  def create() {
    def client = new Client(name:"John")
    println client
  }
}
```

Currently I am always getting null for client. Originally the above was a little more complex on the domain class side but I systematically dumbed it down to see if it was a problem there. I still can not get the above working.

The output is always
scheduler.Client : null

Please let me know if I need to provide anymore information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not null, that's just the default output of the `toString` method that Grails adds. It prints the class name and the id. Since you haven't saved the instance, the id is null. If the instance was null the output would have been `null`, not `scheduler.Client : null`

If you want to see the data in the instance, use the Groovy `dump()` method, e.g.

```
def client = new Client(name:"John")
println client.dump()
```

You could also add a `toString` method that includes the `name` attribute, e.g.

```
package scheduler

class Client {
   String name

   String toString() { name }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I am more used to rails and could not find a good explanation of why the output was that way.